# Have Java 8 for Luna and Java 7 for Juno

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to use both Eclipse Juno and Eclipse Luna simultaneously in my machine, for different projects.

My machine has Java 8 installed. This works perfect with Luna since the projects I have in Luna are exclusive to Java 8.

My projects in Juno need Java 7 strictly. It seems I have a build path issue (I guess it is because I don't have Java 7 in my system).

I downloaded JRE 7 and tried to install it. However, it tells me that I already have Java 8 installed in my machine.

What do I do then? How can I have Java 7 for my Juno projects?

Mac OSX Mavericks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify in the `eclipse.ini` file which JVM you want to use.
The JVM does not even need to be installed, it is enough to unzip it to some folder.

Simply create an entry like this:

```
-vm
C:\Java\JDK\1.6\bin\javaw.exe
```

See also:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

In Eclipse you can add the JVMs without having them installed as well:
Windows / Preferences / Java > Installed JREs

Answer (score 0):

If you would be doing development with Java 7, you need the JDK as opposed to the JRE.

In Eclipse, you make your project `FACETED`, then right click on your Java 7 project and go `Properties`. From there, you can select `Project Facets` and then you can modify the `Java` version you would be using for that particular project.

I have multiple Java versions (JDKs) installed and this is how i control the version i am using in my projects.

Hope this helps!